# RailsAdmin validations on foreign key crashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rails-admin

> Failed to replace tickets because one or more of the new records could
>   not be saved.

My Form model has_many tickets.  A ticket cannot have a form if it has a particular flag set. When i go to test this by trying to assign a ticket to an existing form, it *crashes* rather than pay attention to my validations.

Since its RailsAdmin, I see its just calling update_attribute (which apparently saves nested objects) before doing the error handing of checking if the Form object saves or not.

Is there any known way to get RailAdmin to gracefully catch this validation exception long enough to do its normal error handling for the Form itself failing validation? It's all part of the automatic stuff handling edits/new of an arbitrary object.

I'm using Rails 4.2.0 and RailsAdmin 1.1.1

Edit for Guilermo:

> I have models on rails admin that fail to save because the nested object was invalid. Are you using the nested form field on rails admin? Could you show the rails admin configuration code on the form model and the validation? I'd be happy to help with that.

Whoever created this code used simple default things, the following is the relevant line inside the RailsAdmin config initializer.

```
edit do
  include_all_fields
end
```

Observed behavior is the standard RailsAdmin field where you can search for objects, or pick from a drop down, and select one or more of them to be attached to the current object.

The nested object IS invalid (and as a result the parent object is as well). The problem is that rather than returning the parent object as invalid, the system crashes because the nested object is invalid.

The RailsAdmin code appears to call update_attribute (which throws an uncaught error), and then actually does the save! (along with crash check).  I am basing this on the following code:

https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/lib/rails_admin/config/actions/edit.rb

Specifically:

```
@object.set_attributes(params[@abstract_model.param_key])
          @authorization_adapter && @authorization_adapter.attributes_for(:update, @abstract_model).each do |name, value|
            @object.send("#{name}=", value)
          end
          changes = @object.changes
          if @object.save
            @auditing_adapter && @auditing_adapter.update_object(@object, @abstract_model, _current_user, changes)
            respond_to do |format|
              format.html { redirect_to_on_success }
              format.js { render json: {id: @object.id.to_s, label: @model_config.with(object: @object).object_label} }
            end
          else
            handle_save_error :edit
          end
```

It crashes at  @object.set_attributes.

Comment: I have models on rails admin that fail to save because the nested object was invalid. 
Are you using the nested form field on rails admin? Could you show the rails admin configuration code on the form model and the validation? I'd be happy to help with that.

Comment: Nested form field? Apparently not, whoever came before me just used default things: I'll edit my question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid this problem by not showing the tickets that do not have that flag on your model edit form.

You can do this like this:

```rb
edit do
  field :tickets do
    associated_collection_scope do
      proc { |scope| scope.where(flag: false) }
    end
  end
end
```

Unfortunately this means that you'll have to specify which fields will be shown and you won't be able to use

```rb
include_all_fields
```

You could use the include_fields method for a nicer syntax to do that

```rb
include_fields [:tickets, :other_field, :etc]
```